# Supplying a custom error to +[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:reply:]

Tags: ios, watchkit, uiapplicationdelegate

The `reply` parameter of [`+[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:reply:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:) is a block which takes in `(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error)`.

The `replyInfo` parameter is supplied by the [`-[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:) method.

However, the `reply` parameter of this second method is a block which only takes in a `(NSDictionary *replyInfo)`; there is no `error` parameter.

Is there any way to supply a custom `NSError` as an argument to [`+[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:reply:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:) from my iPhone App, or is that parameter reserved for the system? (E.g. if there was a communication error between the watch and phone.)

---

Here's an example of what I would like to do:

In WatchKit:

```
WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(nil, reply: { (response, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        println("Error: \(error)")
    } else {
        doSomethingUseful()
    }
}
```

In `UIApplicationDelegate`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply {
    if (inBadState) {
       reply(nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:errorDomain code:errorCode userInfo:nil]);
    } else {
       reply([self response], nil);
    }
}
```

Note: This is a stripped down example which doesn't take into account the `userInfo` or `response` parameters; the real usage will take those into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the `error` parameter, unfortunately. What I do is pass any errors as strings and use a common dictionary key. Then, I check for the existence of that key on the WatchKit end and log any errors it finds. Not ideal, to be sure.